# Of a given perimeter, do there exist infinitely many right-angled triangles?

Tags: triangles, pythagorean-triples

I'm a high school student (11th grade, CBSE curriculum). My first language isn't English.

So here's my question:

Having a unique perimeter, let's say $x$ units, how many right-angled triangles, if a finite number of them, do exist? Are there infinitely many right-angled triangles having the same perimeter? How do we prove that, in case it's true or false?

*(Why is my question put on hold as “off-topic”? What does that even mean)*

Comment: You will probably receive more (and more helpful) responses if you include your work and thoughts so far.

Comment: Do you require that the sides of your triangle be rational, or can they be real?  The answers are different.

Comment: The sides must be real.

Comment: There are a finite number of Pythagorean triples for any given perimeter.
Using Euclid's formula, we have

$$P=(m^2-n^2 )+2mn+(m^2+n^2 )=2m^2+2mn$$
And solving for n
$$n=\frac{P-2m^2}{2m}\quad\text{where}\quad\biggl\lceil\sqrt{\frac{P}{2}}\space\space\biggr\rceil\le m\le \frac{P}{2}$$
If you find an integer $n$ for any f(P,m) in the $m$-range you have $m,n$ for a triple. If no values of $m$ in the range yield and integer $n$, there is no triple for that perimeter or you might try using factors of $P$ and, having found one or more, multiply by the co-factor(s).

Comment: After some thinking, I realize that non-Pythagorean triples (with non-integer sides) can qualify under your question. Picture a semi-circle with a triangle within where  the hypotenuse is the diameter and the right-angle vertex touches the curve anywhere. No matter where the right-angle vertex touches the curve, the perimeter will be the same so, YES, the are infinite right triples for a given perimeter.

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS**

We may assume the perimeter is $1$.  Then we want to know the number of solutions, in positive numbers, to $$x^2+y^2=z^2\tag{1}$$ subject to $$x+y+z=1\tag{2}$$  Substitute $(2)$ into $(1)$ to eliminate $z$ and you get $$2x+2y-2xy=1$$

The [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%202x%2B2y-2xy%3D1) of this equation is a hyperbola, but not all the points on it correspond to positive $x,y,z$.

Take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

A selection of a right triangle comes down to choosing lengths $a$ and $b$ for the legs which will then determine the length $c$ of the hypotenuse by the Pythagorean Theorem $$c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}.$$ So a natural rephrasing of the question would be: *Given a positive number $x$ are there infinitely many pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=x$?*

In fact, for each side length $a$ which is between $0$ and $x/2$ there is such a pair. And since there are infinitely many values between $0$ and $x/2$ there are infinitely many right triangles with perimeter $x$.

To actually prove this result you need to use something you will be familiar with if you have taken calculus, the Intermediate Value Theorem or IVT. The IVT states that if you have a continuous (no gaps or breaks in the curve) function $f$ such that $f(a)=c$ and $f(b)=d$, then if some number $q$ is in between $d$ and $e$, there will be a number $p$ that is between $a$ and $b$ such that $f(p)=q$. The IVT is essentially saying that if a curve passes through two values on the vertical ("y") axis, then it must also pass through every value in between.

Solving your problem provides a concrete example of the IVT. Suppose that $a$ is greater than $0$ and less than $x/2$. Think of $a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ as a function in which $a$ is fixed and $b$ is variable. Then when $b=0$, $a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=a+a=2a<x.$ Also, when $b=x$, $a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=a+x+\sqrt{a^2+x^2)}\geq 2x >x.$ For certain values of $b$ the perimeter will be too small and for certain values of $b$ the perimeter will be too big. Therefore by the IVT there must be a $b$ which is just right, for which $a^2+b^2+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=x.$ The IVT is our Goldilocks principle.

Since every value of $a$ between $0$ and $x/2$ corresponds to certain $b$ and a certain right triangle with perimeter $x$ there have to be infinitely many right triangles with perimeter $x$.

Comment: You don't need the intermediate value theorem.  The uncountably many solutions can be given explicitly, by continuing the calculation in my answer.